# Running HMA Pro VPN on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, dns, vpn, openvpn, kali-linux

I've installed HMA VPN on my Kali Linux distro but I'm having problems connecting to a VPN IP address.

I run the command ./hma-vpn.sh -l "Amsterdam" for example, and then I try to connect to a particular IP address by running ./hma-vpn.sh "IP Address".

It runs but then errors out at this point..

```
Checking new IP address...
Mon Dec 22 18:58:27 2014 Initialization Sequence Completed
Failed to load IP address.
```

I read something about how this could be my DNS settings but didn't really find any solution for how to fix that.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I had to modify my /etc/resolv.conf file.

I had to take or comment out the two existing nameserver lines and add the following in there:

```
sudo echo nameserver 208.67.222.222 >> /etc/resolv.conf
sudo echo nameserver 208.67.220.220 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

After adding and saving, I'm able to connect fine to any VPN.

Thanks